# Visual studio skipping lines between functions

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I'm on the preview version of visual studio 2017. And recently after an update my visual studio started doing this:

[image: visual studio 2017 preview]

I have marked the issue with two white circles. As you can see, visual studio adds a visual line break between the functions. How this happened, I don't know. It might be a key combination that I pressed by accident or a setting that is on by default in my version.

What I want to do is turn it off. I want line 255 and 256 in my screenshot to be directly underneath each other again and not have visual studio insert a mandatory "line break" between them. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Hard to tell for a preview version.  I'd look at Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > Advanced for a new option checkbox.

Comment: While I can't be certain about changing it, this is completely normal, to me at least. All of my functions have this gap, but I use TFS at work, and in those gaps it shows me "references | changes | authors/changes." which is very useful

Comment: @HansPassant doesn't appear to be a C# specific issue, it happens on vb.net projects too

Comment: @DarthTommy it is something that started happening me a couple of weeks ago, none of my collegues seem to encounter this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has fixed itself after updating to `Version 15.8.0 Preview 5.0`.